# What is the correct way to test a Next.js/React app that uses the latest version of Material Web Components' web components with Jest?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jestjs, material-ui, web-component

What is the correct way to test a Next.js/React app that uses the latest version of Material Web Components' web components with Jest? I'm encountering: "TypeError: this.attachInternals is not a function."

I've mocked that function like this:

```
global.HTMLElement.prototype.attachInternals = () => ({
  setFormValue: () => {},
  setValidity: () => {}
})
```

But I have a button with name="Redirect to Sign in" and role="link" that, when using this mock, loses both the name and role. This prevents me from performing tests, for example, using screen.getByRole, and it causes the snapshots to be incorrect.